# How to track the user locally, when user is using some other app and return back to its own app?

Tags: java, android

There is an app: say MYAPP. I want to track the user movement that when user using MYAPP ,when user started to using another app say gmail, whatsapp etc and when return back to MYAPP.
I was trying to handle it by making a list with generic type in Application class and use that list on onResume() and onPause() method. but it is not possible for me to track whether user is coming from another app or MYAPP because onResume() and onPause() will be called in both condition.

Please help me. Appropriate answer will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

This method will return you list of active apps:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
        if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
            for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                //Get Active Processes Here
            }
        }
    }
```

You should call this method on onPause and onResume of your activity.

Comment: Not working for me. If we use above method on onPause(), and move to another activity then, firstly u will recieve '100' for app is running  and then '400'  for app in background, at the same time. so then how will we identify that either user switched to other activity or app is in background